# Proof: $\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty R^n$ is transitive closure of $R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, relations

I have this exercise:
Let $R\subseteq A^2$ be any relation. Proove $\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty R^n$ is the transitive closure of $R$.

I have no idea what to do. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Well, you could begin writing down the definition of transitive closure, and call $T$ the transitive closure of $R$. After that, you should prove by double inclusion that $T= \cup_n R^n$.

Comment: How do you define transitive closure of $R$? Is it: the intersection of all transitive $S \supseteq R$?

Answer (score 3):

If $S$ is any transitive relation such that $R \subseteq S$, then show that $R^n \subseteq S$, so $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} R^n \subseteq S$.

On the other hand, show directly that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} R^n$ is indeed transitive. And it certainly contains $R$ so...